# Check if ANY item in an array is in a certain state: coffeescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript, states, framerjs

I have an array of buttons with a 'selected' and 'deselected' state. How do I go about checking if any button in the array is in the 'selected' state.

So essentially I want something like (using Framer coffeescript):

```
for button in buttonArray
    button.onClick ->
       this.stateCycle("selected", "default")

       if any button in buttonArray state.current == "selected"
           activateMainButton()
       else
           deactivateMainButton()
```

Here is my prototype: http://share.framerjs.com/11abcrlne5op/ (go to the ethnicity section).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if by 'any', you mean all of them or some of them, but there are the `Array.prototype` methods called [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), and [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

Syntax is `buttonArray.some(button => button.state.current == "selected")`

This is in javascript, coffescript should have something similar

You can also use the lodash library's version [some](https://lodash.com/docs#some) and [every](https://lodash.com/docs#every).

Or just make a counter in a loop to count them.

Comment: I guess I want 1? ex: I have 10 buttons in my array. I can click each button to cycle states between selected and deselected. If at least 1 button is in the selected state -> run activateMainButton() (this button is not part of the button Array). Here is my prototype. go to the ethnicity section http://share.framerjs.com/11abcrlne5op/

Comment: Also my programming knowledge is not very advanced, so forgive me.

Comment: So you are looking for the `some` method, which will return true if at least one of the items will return true for the input function you give it.

Comment: Quite a bit simpler for the callback to be `button => button.selected`. ;-). Plain JS can be [*embedded in coffeescript*](http://devdocs.io/coffeescript/index#embedded).

Comment: Gotcha. I think I understand but I'm not quite sure where to put it in my code  https://screencast.com/t/EttN36Gg

Comment: Nevermind, got it! Thank you! this search was also helpful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every